# How to change a selected text in a textarea into anchor tag

Tags: jquery, anchor

in So and many posting sites we can change our selected text into a anchor tag here how should i change a selected text within a textarea into a anchor element?

for example

```
<a class="button add-anchor">add-anchor</a> 

<textarea>
       hello am name
 <textarea>    

  <a class="ppst button">Post</a>
```

here am having a textarea used to post a content here, i need to add some links for a word.it can made little easier when using a div with `contenteditable` option here how should i make a selected text in a textarea into anchor tag after it get posted. am completely struck ed here.

Answer (score 0):

You can't place any 'Active Link' inside a text area. A text area is designed to displaying text only content. Instead of that you can use div and using some css make div as a text area.

Comment: they use javascript editor see list here http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/design/10-best-wysiwyg-text-and-html-editors-for-your-next-project/